# Insert a series of values into pd.dataframe randomly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe and what I want to do is overwrite X entries of that dataframe with a new value I set. The new entries have to be at a random position, but they have to be in order. Like I have a Column with random numbers, and want to overwrite 20 of them in a row with the new value x.

I tried `df.sample(x)` and then update the dataframe, but I only get individual entries. But I need the X new entries in a row (consecutively).

Somebody got a solution? I'm quite new to Python and have to get into it for my master thesis.

CLARIFICATION:

My dataframe has 5 columns with almost 60,000 rows, each row for 10 minutes of the year.

- One Column is 'output' with electricity production values for that 10 minutes.
- For 2 consecutive hours (120 consecutive minutes, hence 12 consecutive rows) of the year I want to lower that production to 60%. I want it to happen at a random time of the year.
- Another column is 'status', with information about if the production is reduced or not.

I tried:

```py
df_update = df.sample(12)
df_update.status = 'reduced'
df.update(df_update)
df.loc[('status) == 'reduced', ['production']] *=0.6
```

which does the trick for the total amount of time (12*10 minutes), but I want 120 consecutive minutes and not separated.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample input and what your expected output would be

Comment: The crucial phrase is '120 consecutive minutes' or '12 consecutive rows'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to get a random value and just index the next 12 entries to be 0.6. I think this is what you want.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'output':np.random.randn(20),'status':[0]*20})
idx = df.sample(1).index.values[0]
df.loc[idx:idx+11,"output"]=0.6
df.loc[idx:idx+11,"status"]=1
```

Comment: No problem, if you want to do this for every year I would recommend splitting each year into separate dataframes. Otherwise you will need a new idx for each year and might risk df.loc[idx:idx+11, :] running into the next year. All be it if that's ok then you're good to go

Comment: Just one more thing: If I want to set those 2 hours to a specific time of the year, how would I use that the idx? I also have a column named 'time'. So can I just set:
```python
idx = df['time']='xx'.index.values[0]
```python
and do the same?

Comment: Do you mean you want to pick a random index within a subset of the year?

Comment: No, this time nothing is random. I set one row of the status to 'reduced' by using
df.loc[(df['time']=='01.01.2017 00:10'), ['status']] = 'reduced'
and want to set the next 12 rows as 'reduced' too.

Comment: I would do a similar thing to above, except find the idx for wherever you want to set. In this case it would be idx=df[df['time']=='01.01.2017 00:10']].index.values[0], then you can just use the df.loc[idx:idx+11,'status']="reduced"